# Ignore loading in selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I'm writing a selenium code in java that does the below.

1. Open the page.
2. Close the promotion banner.
3. Check a category from the left.
4. Click on the product.
5. `sysout` name, go back to the previous page.
6. Click on the next product.

Currently, the code is working fine. But I want to know when I go back, is there a way that I can ignore the waiting spinner which is coming on the image, directly click, and proceed? 'coz this is the step that is taking a lot of my time. Here is a screen of what I am saying.

[image]

Here is my code.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class tesCode {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/chromedriver");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.ediblearrangements.com/fruit-arrangements");
        driver.findElement(By.id("imgClose")).click();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
        List<WebElement> catList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("/descendant::a[@ftype='id']"));
        for (int cat = 0; cat < 2; cat++) {
            driver.findElements(By.xpath("/descendant::a[@ftype='id']")).get(cat).click();
            List<WebElement> prodList = driver
                    .findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='divArrangementList']/ul//li/descendant::a[1]"));
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                prodList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='divArrangementList']/ul/li/descendant::a[1]"));
                wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(prodList.get(i)));
                if (prodList.get(i) != null) {
                    prodList.get(i).click();
                    driver.findElement(By.className("arrnamewithsup")).getText();
                    driver.navigate().back();
                }
            }
        }
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

And also is there any other way of making this fast.

Thanks

Comment: what if you click the item before the image has been loaded?

Comment: what is your goal? print "product name" or just go back and forth?

Comment: @lucasnguyen17, yes. you are correct

Comment: @AlexeyR. it should work

Comment: What if you change the page load strategy: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/page_loading_strategy/

Answer (score 0):

Nope, By default - selenium will wait for the page load. We cannot control it. We can add wait conditions, only for additional wait required - not to reduce them.